# Did the Rotherham rapists shout Allahu Akbar at their sentencing?

Tags: united-kingdom

[The Rotherham scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotherham_child_sexual_exploitation_scandal) is a case of widespread organised child sexual abuse in the city of Rotherham in England. Over a period of years, more than 1,400 girls, many of them pre-teens, were raped and trafficked by a loose consortium of men. The men were all Muslim immigrants or sons of immigrants. When the scandal finally came to light in 2014, city officials said that they had been reluctant to do anything about the problem for fear of being accused of racism.

The [Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/2769601/rotherham-sex-abuse-gang-allahu-akbar-jailed/) reports at their sentencing hearing they say:

> There were emotional and chaotic scenes at Sheffield Crown Court after two of the defendants shouted “***Allahu Akbar***” as they were led from the dock.

Is it true that the convicted rapists shouted that as they were led away?

Comment: I can see plenty of newspaper articles stating this is the case, however you're asking despite spotting this in a newspaper article. What level of evidence would you like to see/would convince you?
[1](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/02/02/rotherham-child-sex-abuse-woman-made-pregnant-aged-12-believes/),
[2](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/rotherham-child-abuse-gang-shout-allahu-akbar-court-after-being-handed-80-year-jail-term-1604539),
[3](http://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/697583/Rotherham-abuse-scandal-child-grooming-gangs-industrial-scale-victims-CSE)

Comment: @LioElbammalf  That would do it.  Worried about the Sun, because it's the Sun.

Comment: Okay, I'll pop them into an answer then.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If it were a Christian crying "May God have mercy on my soul!" when being sent down for some crime s/he believed the Bible condoned, it would, I suspect, be of little note. From The Telegraph article, it seems it was supporters of the perpetrators and victims shouting back from the public gallery that caused the kerfuffle after hearing the call.

Comment: The phrase "Allahu Akbar" has several uses and is often mischaracterised by the west. I've seen videos shot by Iraqi citizens of airstrikes landing on buildings, and the people behind the camera cried "Allahu Akbar" on seeing the destruction. I doubt they were taking credit for the airstrikes, or celebrating them, given that they were destroying parts of the town that these people lived in. A western analogue would be shouting "oh my God" when traumatic things happen. Without seeing their expressions - and getting some cultural context - it's hard to say what they meant by it in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This case is also repeated in several other newspaper articles. Whilst this doesn't prove it is the case it raises it above the level of belief held whilst reading articles in the Sun.

[telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/02/02/rotherham-child-sex-abuse-woman-made-pregnant-aged-12-believes/),
[international business times](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/rotherham-child-abuse-gang-shout-allahu-akbar-court-after-being-handed-80-year-jail-term-1604539),
[express](http://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/697583/Rotherham-abuse-scandal-child-grooming-gangs-industrial-scale-victims-CSE)

Googling the case will provide you with many more newspaper articles.

Comment: But, are these independent sources?